# Padding percentage inside a table with table-layout: fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table, padding

Is this a way to set a percentage padding inside a table cell without hard coding a width of this cell?

I have a table with dynamically changing number of columns, each of which must have an equal width, so I set:

```
table
{ 
   table-layout: fixed; 
}
```

It works great, but I also want to set a percentage padding inside several cells. Unfortunately, because of uncertain number of columns, I can't set a particular width to these cells.

If I just set:

```
table tbody tr td.with_padding
{
   padding: 20%;
}
```

it looks like a padding for sells is calculated depending on width of whole table rather than of particular cell.

How can I solve this with pure CSS, if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the % padding will resolve against the parent element, which is the `tr`, which will be the same width as the table. If you want the % padding to resolve against the cell's width, you can put another `div` inside the cell and put all the cell's content in this inner `div`.

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table style="background: green; table-layout: fixed;">
  <td style="width: 100px; background: orange;">
    <div style="padding: 20%;">
      I have % padding
    </div>
  </td>
  <td style="width: 100px; background: orange;">
    I have no padding and am really really really really long and stuff
  </td>
</table>
```